# Firebase auth with Google sign-in doesn't work in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using Firebase Auth with Google Sign-in in my flutter app.

And I have a problem about this authentication feature.
It doesn't work only in release mode in Android.
(But it works very well in 'Android debug', 'IOS debug', 'IOS release')

Below is my crashlytics message.

> "Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError"
> "[firebase_auth/unknown] l4.k: An internal error has occurred. [ Instantiation of JsonResponse failed! class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.e ]. Error thrown null."

I registered SHA fingerprints in the Firebase Settings of this project.
Actually, I registered three SHA-1 prints and three SHA-256 prints. (debug, release, key.jks)

Especially for the release key, I checked over 10 times from my PlayConsole App Signining Certificate.

Actually, I already have an experience to deploy apps using FirebaseAuth with Google Sign-in.
And It worked very well both in debug and release.
So, I would say I am pretty well informed of how to set this authentication process.

But this time, I totally have no idea.
If I did something wrong in my Flutter code, then it has not to work also in debug mode.
But it works very well in debug mode.

So I want to get some information about this bug.

Can you guys please help me out?

```
static final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(clientId: null);
  GoogleSignInAccount? user;

  Future<void> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      user = await googleSignIn.signIn();

      if (user == null) {
        return;
      } else {
        final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: (await user!.authentication).accessToken,
          idToken: (await user!.authentication).idToken,
        );

        Logger().i('[OAuth signInMethod] ${credential.signInMethod}');
        Logger().i('[OAuth idToken] ${credential.idToken}');
        Logger().i('[OAuth accessToken] ${credential.accessToken}');

        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

        Get.back();
        customToast('로그인 되었습니다.', k_mainColor, () {});
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e, stackTrace) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(e, stackTrace, fatal: true);

      Logger().w(e.message);
    }
  }

  signOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();

    customToast('로그아웃 되었습니다.', k_mainColor, () {});
  }
```

- I registered SHA fingerprints in the Firebase Settings of this project.
- I did flutter clean many times.
- I did flutter doctor -v. And there were no problems.
- I removed code about proguard. remove it or not. Both didn't work.

Comment: Just an idea: in Google Cloud Console (not Firebase), under `APIs & Services` there is a `Credentials` menu. Here you have `auto created...` credentials. Check `API Keys` list for `Android key...`.  If there is a restriction set, fingerprints need to be added here as well.  Also check that you have the proper fingerprints for OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Since `Integrate API` adds it's own app signing keys (`App signing key certificate`), for me it was sometimes necessary to add this in Google Cloud Console. But maybe it doesn't help with your situtation.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Thank you :) But it was auto created in Credentials of Google Cloud Console.